# How to create the vector 2:10 and 10:2 using the seq function

Tags: r, vector, seq

I need to use `seq()` to create the vector `(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2)`, but I'm stuck. I've done quite a bit of YouTube-ing and reading online, but can't find a specific enough solution.

Any help is appreciated, but please use the seq function when making recommendations.

Comment: Read the help pages of `:` and `c()`.

Comment: I have provided step-by-step answers for you. Kindly go through it.

Comment: [You should take care of this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `seq` function, you need to following two steps:

Step-1 Generate sequence from 2 to 10 using following code:

```
a<-seq(from=2,to = 10)
```

Step-2 Generate sequence from 10 to 2 using following code:

```
b<-seq(from=9,to = 2)
```

Now, combine above two results using following code:

```
data<-c(a,b)
```

The output should as follow:

```
> data
[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2
```

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
unlist(mapply(seq, c(2,9), c(10,2), c(1,-1), SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
#  [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2
```

Comment: i never downvote @akrun, i have joined SO to learn and share knowledge, not to prove others wrong.

Comment: also OP wanted to use `seq`.

Answer (score 0):

According to `help(":")`,

> [...] `from:to` is equivalent to `seq(from, to)`, and generates a sequence from `from` to `to` in steps of `1` or `-1`.

This is the justification to offer

```
c(2:10, 9:2)
#[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2
```

as solution. Here, `seq()` is implicitely used but doesn't appear verbatim.